# Agregar textos en las esquinas de las imágenes con CSS

Tags: php, css, imagen

Tengo estas etiquetas `li` de productos y quiero ajustar unos estilos y no sé cómo hacerlo.

Quiero que el nuevo este en la parte inferior de la imagen y el porciento de descuento (`%`) salga en la esquina superior de la imagen.

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="hProductItems clearfix">
    <li class="span3 clearfix">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href=""><img src="img/212x192.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="thumbSetting">
        <div class="thumbTitle">
          <a href="#" class="invarseColor">
            Foliomania the designer portfolio brochure
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbPrice">
          if($value["precio"] == 0){
            echo '<span>GRATIS</span>';
          }else{
            if($value["oferta"] != 0){
              echo '  <span><span class="strike-through">USD $'.$value["precio"].'</span> USD $'.$value["precioOferta"].'</span>';
            }else{
              echo '  <span> USD $'.$value["precio"].'</span>';
            }
          }
          if($value["nuevo"] != 0){
            echo '<span>Nuevo</span> ';
          }
          if($value["oferta"] != 0){
            echo '<span>'.$value["descuentoOferta"].'% off</span>';
          }
        </div>
        <div class="thumbButtons">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-small" data-title="+To Cart" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
            <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-small" data-title="+To WishList" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
            <i class="icon-heart"></i>
          </button>

          <button class="btn btn-small" data-title="+To Compare" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
            <i class="icon-refresh"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <ul class="rating">
          <li><i class="star-on"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star-on"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star-on"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star-on"></i></li>
          <li><i class="star-off"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Quiero poner el nuevo en la esquina inferior y el porciento (%) en la esquina superior]

Me gustaría que se viera de esta manera:

[image: Así]

Comment: Que necesitas hacer?

Comment: Quieres ajustarlos ¿Y que queden como?

Comment: ajustes como el span nuevo que quede encima de la imagen en la esquina inferior derecha y el span de el prociento descuento e la esquina superior izquierda